# AD Connect - On Premise AD and Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, active-directory, synchronization

I am setting up few VMs in Azure and would like to sync on-premises Active Directory with Azure Active Directory.

I am just wondering if I need site-to-site VPN between on-premises and Azure or AD Connect will work over internet connection.

Comment: Please see if this links helps - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD Connect works over Internet.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/#comments
*"Yes, Azure AD Connect will work over Internet. No VPN is required. Communication to Azure AD is using web services over HTTPS (and HTTP)."*